# How to deal with discrete time system in GEKKO?

Tags: gekko

I am dealing with a discrete time system with sampling time of 300s.

My question is that how to express the state equation or output eqatuin like

```
x(k+1)=A*x(k)+B*u(k)
y(k)=C*x(k)
```

where `x(k)` is the state and `y(k)` is the output. I have all the value of A, B, C matrix.

I found some information about discrete time system on webpage https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/DiscreteStateSpace

I want to know whether there is another way to express state equation other than

```
x,y,u = m.state_space(A,B,C,D=None,discrete=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The discrete state space model is the preferred way to pose your model. You could also convert your equations to a [discrete time series form](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/ARXTimeSeries) or to a continuous state space form. These all are equivalent forms. Another way to write your model is to use `IMODE=2` (algebraic equations) but this is much more complicated. Here is an [example of MIMO identification](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ModelIdentification) where we estimate ARX parameters with IMODE=2. I recommend the `m.state_space` model and to use it with `IMODE>=4`.

Here is a [pendulum state space model example](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ControlTypes).

[image: pendulum state space]

and a [flight control state space model](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ModelSimulation).

[image: flight control]

These both use continuous state space models but the methods are similar to what is needed for your application.

Comment: I have one more question abtou objective function. My prediction horizon is 10. What does the objective function m.Obj((x-xset)'Q(x-xset)+u'Ru) mean? Does it means the objecive function is sum of 10 values (current value and 9 future values)? Or it means it only contains the objective value at current step?

Comment: All values in the control horizon (10) are included in the objective function. You could set a parameter and give it ones and zeros to selectively pick points that you would like to drive to `xset` such as m.Obj((x-xset)*Q*(x-xset)*p+u'*R*u*p)